# How to format ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instance to specified format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instance like `2014-12-22 05:54:34 UTC`, but I only want to keep the date info `2014-12-22`

I tried Rail's `to_formatted_s`, but it didn't work for me.

```
<%= item.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:db) %>
```

Which displays: `2014-12-22 05:54:34`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime):

```
> date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

where,

```
%Y - Year with century
%m - Month of the year (01..12)
%d - Day of the month (01-31)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[7] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone)
=> true
[8] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.to_s
=> "2014-12-22 17:16:39 +1100"
[9] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
=> "2014-12-22"
[11] pry(main)> Time.zone.now.strftime("%F")
=> "2014-12-22"
```

Refer
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```rb
Time.current.strftime("%d %b %Y")
=> "11 Jan 2021"
```

[Here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)'s the full list:

```
%a - The abbreviated weekday name (“Sun”)

%A - The full weekday name (“Sunday”)

%b - The abbreviated month name (“Jan”)

%B - The full month name (“January”)

%c - The preferred local date and time representation

%d - Day of the month (01..31)

%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)

%I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)

%j - Day of the year (001..366)

%m - Month of the year (01..12)

%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

%p - Meridian indicator (“AM” or “PM”)

%S - Second of the minute (00..60)

%U - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week (00..53)

%W - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday as the firstday of the first week (00..53)

%w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)

%x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time

%X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date

%y - Year without a century (00..99)

%Y - Year with century

%Z - Time zone name

%% - Literal “%” character
```

And [another source](https://strftime.org/)